# Google App Script - creating a dynamic spreadsheet menu where the menu items are based off the results of a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to Google App Script and not the most knowledgeable when it comes to coding in general.
I am trying to make a dynamic menu that creates the menu items by checking all of the tabs within one spreedsheet to see if there is anything in a certain cell range (the same cell range, ex: C3:I12) on each tab and if yes, then a link to that tab is added as a menu option with the menu option being named after that tab named. If not, then it would not be added.
Ideally it would refresh/update the menu after any edits to the sheet.
Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I used a different link than the one listed as a duplicate (that one feels very confusing, especially for someone brand new to App Script). Here is a pastebin with code that should help you specifically, as well as the reference link that I used to create this so you could better understand what I did >> https://pastebin.com/k9WQxF47

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 Thank you for answering my question. I have tried to edit the code you provided to produce my desired result but I have not had success. I don't understand how to make it evaluate the range I need for if it's empty or not and then create the menu items based on that and then make the menu items take me to the tab it is named after.